# Detecting and pasting cntrl+v in Electron

Tags: electron, keyboard-shortcuts, detect, pasting

I'm trying to make an electron application that changes what's on your clipboard.

So for instance, when you do "cntrl+v" 2 times in a row it'll display 2 different words.

Is there a way to do this? Since when you use globalKeybinds, it doesn't paste anything when you press cntrl+v.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site isn't mean for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working as intended, then we can help you with that.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a work around to this that i have implemented in one of my project.
what you can do is register a global shortcut something like this and call a function to write the desired text to the clipboard.
it's not the elegant way at all since it required 2 key presses but that's what i came up when i worked on it.

```
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+1', () => {
 trigger_paste(1);
});
function trigger_paste(index) {
 let tuple=list[index]
 clipboard.writeImage(nativeImage.createFromDataURL(tuple.buffer));
}
```